# Why is my ServiceBusTrigger not getting triggered?

Tags: c#, azure-functions, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-topics, azure-servicebus-subscriptions

I have a Azure Function App that process some messages from Azure Service Bus Topic. I have some messages passed to the ASB and there are messages coming under my topic's subscription. However when I run my app locally which points to that specific subscription, it still doesn't get triggered. I do have configured my app properly with all the connection string. How would you suggest to diagnose this issue?

Just for context: I have it configured in my local settings with needed parameters.

Answer (score 0):

- Check your `connection` property of `ServiceBusTrigger` attribute which should refer to `ServiceBusConnectionString`.
- Now, you need to provide the same name in `local.settings.json` for local and app settings for azure.
- Below is the sample code for ServiceBusTrigger with Azure Functions.

```html
 [FunctionName("ServiceBusQueueTriggerCSharp")]                    
    public static void Run(
        [ServiceBusTrigger("myqueue", Connection = "ServiceBusConnection")] 
        string myQueueItem,
        Int32 deliveryCount,
        DateTime enqueuedTimeUtc,
        string messageId,
        ILogger log)
    {
        log.LogInformation($"C# ServiceBus queue trigger function processed message: {myQueueItem}");
        log.LogInformation($"EnqueuedTimeUtc={enqueuedTimeUtc}");
        log.LogInformation($"DeliveryCount={deliveryCount}");
        log.LogInformation($"MessageId={messageId}");
    }
```

- Check this [Microsoft Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-service-bus-trigger?tabs=in-process,extensionv5&pivots=programming-language-csharp) for complete information regards to creation of Azure Function with Azure ServiceBus trigger.

Comment: I did have the connection string property in my local settings and have the same name. It was working like a week ago and its not working currently.

Comment: - Try force resyncing your triggers by hitting the refresh button. this should work if not try below steps.
- Check if you can see messages in dead letter queue.
- Check whether your Azure functions going idle for some time if so enable **Always On**

Comment: Can you elaborate more to this? How do I force resync when I'm testing locally? Also, messages are not going to dead letter queue. It is still in Active.

Comment: @PPPP ,Are you still facing this issue? If not, Can you let me know how you solved this? because, I am facing the same issue.